# Customise leaflet popup scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, leaflet

I have a leaflet popup. The scroll bar is currently the default.

I want to use instead a custom scroller such as the one developed by [malihu](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/). I have included all the libraries and css. However, I am not sure where to add the tags to initialise the custom scroller. I have tried directly wrapping the content in the tag, defined it as `popupstring` :

```
<div class="mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="rounded-dark"> <p> some overflow content </p> </div>
```

and used `mypopup.setContent(popupstring)`. This did not work. I've also tried creating a container with a height first, to contain the content. Also did not work.

How can I change the look of the default leaflet scrollbar? I want to change the scroll bar on the left to the scrollbar on the right:

[image: default scroll bar]  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I figured it out. Basically added this line after adding the popup to the map, so as to change the scroll, and it worked. Also did not need the tags to be in the popup content.

```
$(".leaflet-popup-scrolled").mCustomScrollbar({
theme: "rounded-dark"
});
```

Also need this if the popups are added dynamically, so that the custom scrollbar gets updated the first time

```
$(".leaflet-popup-scrolled").mCustomScrollbar("update");
```